# Align a data label below a point on a bubble graph (Chart.JS)

Tags: javascript, css, chart.js, chart.js2

I am trying to position a label related to the dataset below a point on a bubble graph and to have the value displayed on top of the point.

I have tried returning two different values, but it only allows me to return one.

Because of this I have returned both values within the same string.

Is it possible to return the label and position it below the value of the dataset and to put the value above the point of the dataset?

If it isn't possible would it be possible to somehow get the text to align to the center after the line break I have added to the string?

[Here is what I have so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EU0o6.png)

[This is what I am trying to achieve, but with the value above the bubble](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IF9Rs.png)

Here is my code so far:

```
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');

var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {

    type: 'bubble',

    data: {
        datasets: [
            {
                label: 'Top',
                data: [
                    {x: 110, y: 0, r: 12, name: "Performance"}
                ],
                backgroundColor: "rgba(255,255,255,1)",
                borderColor: "rgba(91,182,209,1)",
                borderWidth: 2,
                hoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(255,255,255,1)",
                hoverBorderWidth : 2
            },
            {
                label: 'Average',
                data: [
                    {x: 75, y: 0, r: 12, name: "Performance"}
                ],
                backgroundColor: "rgba(255,255,255,1)",
                borderColor: "rgba(91,182,209,1)",
                borderWidth: 2,
                hoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(255,255,255,1)",
                hoverBorderWidth : 2
            },
            {
                label: 'You 2017',
                data: [
                    {x: 55, y: 0, r: 15, name: "Performance"}
                ],
                backgroundColor: "rgba(255,255,255,1)",
                borderColor: "rgba(91,182,209,1)",
                borderWidth: 2,
                hoverBackgroundColor : "rgba(255,255,255,1)",
                hoverBorderWidth : 2
            },
            {
                label: 'You 2018',
                data: [
                    {x: 90, y: 0, r: 15, name: "Performance"} // The labe needs to be
                ],
                backgroundColor: "rgba(255,255,255,1)",
                borderColor: "rgba(91,182,209,1)",
                borderWidth: 2,
                hoverBackgroundColor : "rgba(255,255,255,1)",
                hoverBorderWidth : 2
            }
        ]
    },
    options: {
        legend: {
            display: false
        },
        plugins: {
            datalabels: {
                anchor: function (context) {
                    var value = context.dataset.data[context.dataIndex];
                    return value.x < 1000 ? 'end' : 'center';
                },
                align: function (context) {
                    var value = context.dataset.data[context.dataIndex];
                    return value.x < 1000 ? 'end' : 'center';
                },
                color: function (context) {
                    var value = context.dataset.data[context.dataIndex];
                    return value.x < 1000 ? context.dataset.borderColor : 'white';
                },
                font: {
                    weight: 'bold'
                },
                formatter: function (value, context) {
                    ctx.textAlign = "center";
                    return context.dataset.label + "\n" + Math.round(value.x);
                },
                offset: 2,
                padding: 0
            }
        },
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                id: 'first-y-axis',
                type: 'linear',
                ticks: {
                    min: 0,
                    max: 1,
                    stepSize: 1,
                    display: false
                },
                gridLines: {
                    display: false,
                    drawBorder: false
                }
            }],
            xAxes: [
                {
                    id: 'first-x-axis',
                    ticks: {
                        min: 50, // Controls where axis starts
                        max: 120, // Controls where axis finishes
                        stepSize: 70 // Control the gap between the first x-axis value and the last x-axis value
                    },
                    gridLines: {
                        display: false,
                        lineWidth: 3 // Width of bottom line
                    }
                }
            ]

        }
    }

});
```

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated ^_^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured this out by applying 'textAlign' within the charts parameters and set it to centre.

You can see this in the code below:

```
plugins: {
    datalabels: {
        anchor: function (context) {
            var value = context.dataset.data[context.dataIndex];
            return value.x < 1000 ? 'end' : 'center';
        },
        align: function (context) {
            var value = context.dataset.data[context.dataIndex];
            return value.x < 1000 ? 'end' : 'center';
        },
        color: function (context) {
            var value = context.dataset.data[context.dataIndex];
            return value.x < 1000 ? context.dataset.borderColor : 'white';
        },
        textAlign: 'center',
        font: {
            weight: 'bold',
            alignment: 'right' // Is this the place to be doing this?
        },
        formatter: function (value, context) {
            return context.dataset.label + '\n' + Math.round(value.x);
        },
        offset: 2,
        padding: 0
    }
},
```

Hope this helps ^^